# How would I flip an edge piece in a 3x3 without messing anything up except for flipping that one piece?

Tags: rubiks-cube

I am new to picture cubes and I want to know how to flip an edge piece on a picture cube 3x3 **without** messing anything else up.

Like here from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Comment: This is not possible (with normal moves only and without taking the cube apart) unless there is another edge piece that you can flip at the same time. Maybe there is another edge piece that looks the same when it becomes flipped?

Comment: For one thing, those two corner pieces look incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Turn the top layer 45 degrees, insert a wide screwdriver or a flat spoon handle below the edge piece and pop it out.

This is the only way, because edge pieces can only ever be flipped in pairs.

Flipping in pairs is done identically in picture cubes and regular ones. (The only difference is that on a picture cube the center pieces have an orientation, which is not very difficult to fix after first solving the whole cube the regular way.)

Answer (score 1):

This just cannot be done, edges can be flipped only by two, because of parity rules. Any 'atomic' turn results in an even permutation of the elements, so any sequence of turns results in even permutations as well.

You can find more detailed explanations [here](https://www.ryanheise.com/cube/cube_laws.html).